# Filtering and Merging 2 HashMap's in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have one Map which has a key - ItemType an enum and a set of Item Names (String)

`Map<ItemType, Set<String> itemTypesAndNames;`

eg. 
 key: ItemType1, value: a1, a2, a3 
key: ItemType2, value: b1, b2, b3 
key: ItemType3, value: c1, c2, c 3

The second map is

```
Map<String, ItemId> itemNamesAndIds;
```

eg. 
Key: a1, value: 1234556-434 
key: a2, value: 4324234-5453
key: b1  value: 3t5dgsfdfdsf 
and so on

I want to create a new map with ItemType and a set of itemTypeIds 
`Map <ItemType, Set<ItemId>>`

eg 
key: ItemType1, value: 1234556-434, 4324234-545
key: ItemType2, value: 3t5dgsfdfdsf
and so on

```
public class ItemId {
private final String id;
public static ItemId of(String id) { 
return new ItemId (id)}
 }
}

public enum ItemType {
 ITEM_TYPE_1("ItemType1");
 ITEM_TYPE_2("ItemType2");
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried... It is easy to give you an answer, but how you approached it? What is wrong with your approach? Those are questions that we can help you with.

Comment: Not certain why this was closed for details or clarify.  It was clear what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach.  Although I used some stream processing to prepare some demonstration data, I avoided it in the final solution to keep the processing more efficient (based on my testing) since I didn't know the size of your maps.

I also modified your `enum` and `class` to enable their use.

First, create the `itemTypesAndNames` map.

```
Map<ItemType, Set<String>> itemTypesAndNames = Map.of(
        ItemType.ITEM_TYPE_1,
        Set.of("a1", "a2", "a3"),
        ItemType.ITEM_TYPE_2,
        Set.of("b1", "b2", "b3"),
        ItemType.ITEM_TYPE_3,
        Set.of("c1", "c2", "c3"));

itemTypesAndNames.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
ITEM_TYPE_2=[b2, b1, b3]
ITEM_TYPE_3=[c1, c3, c2]
ITEM_TYPE_1=[a3, a2, a1]
```

Now create the `itemNamesAndIds` map

```
Supplier<ItemId> itemId = () -> new ItemId(Integer
        .toString((int)(Math.random() * 89999) + 10000));

Map<String, ItemId> itemNamesAndIds = itemTypesAndNames
        .values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                k -> itemId.get()));

itemNamesAndIds.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
a1=83334
c3=99557
b2=18211
a2=91979
b3=41222
a3=78181
c1=38114
c2=56413
b1=68386
```

Create a target map and simply iterate thru the types and names, creating
an entry for the name if it exists in the `itemNamesAndIds` map. `computeIfAbsent`
creates the target `set` if it isn't already present.

```
Map<ItemType, Set<ItemId>> typesAndIds = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<ItemType, Set<String>> e : itemTypesAndNames
        .entrySet()) {
    for (String name : e.getValue()) {
        if (itemNamesAndIds.containsKey(name)) {
            typesAndIds
                    .computeIfAbsent(e.getKey(),
                            v -> new HashSet<>())
                    .add(itemNamesAndIds.get(name));
        }
    }
}

typesAndIds.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints something like

```
ITEM_TYPE_3=[99557, 38114, 56413]
ITEM_TYPE_1=[83334, 78181, 91979]
ITEM_TYPE_2=[18211, 68386, 41222]
```

The data objects.

```
class ItemId {
    private final String id;
    
    public ItemId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public static ItemId of(String id) {
        return new ItemId(id);
    }
    
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return id;
    }
}

enum ItemType {
    ITEM_TYPE_1("ItemType1"),
    ITEM_TYPE_2("ItemType2"),
    ITEM_TYPE_3("ItemType3");

    private String itemType;

    private ItemType(String t) {
        this.itemType = t;
    }
    
    public String getType() {
        return itemType;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with you with the streams/efficiency comment. Great answer

Answer (score 1):

The values in the `Set<String>` should be remapped into `Set<ItemId>` (possibly keeping only `ids` available in `itemNamesAndIds` map):

```java
Map<ItemType, Set<ItemId>> remapped = itemTypesAndNames.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey,
            e -> e.getValue().stream()
                .filter(itemNamesAndIds::containsKey)
                .map(itemNamesAndIds::get)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet())
        ));
```

---

**Update**
If two maps with the same structure `Map<Key, Set<Value>>` have to be merged it may be implemented using `toMap` collector with the merge function:

```java
Map<Key, Set<Value>> map1 = ...; // init map1
Map<Key, Set<Value>> map2 = ...; // init map2

Map<Key, Set<Value>> merged = Stream.concat(
        map1.entrySet().stream(), map2.entrySet().stream()
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (v1, v2) -> { v1.addAll(v2); return v1; } // assuming that the sets are not immutable
    ));
```

Comment: Thank you for this. If i have 2 Maps ```Map<ItemType, Set<ItemId>>``` and if i want to merge them how to do it? I tried putIfAbsent but that only checks the ItemType and not the ItemId.id. any suggestions please?